# Subset clusterProfiler compareClusterResult object in R

Tags: r, subset, bioinformatics, rna-seq

I am using the clusterProfiler package in R to do gene set enrichment analyses. I have the basic code working, but I would like to subset the results object `compareClusterResult` to only include a specific subset of pathways (i.e. keeping only non-disease pathways). I have created a list of non-disease pathways using the `gage` package, but cannot figure out how to subset the `compareClusterResult` object based on that list.

Here is a small subset of the data I'm analyzing:

```
library(clusterProfiler)

dput(de_list)
list(fb = c("K08193", "K09851", "K07874", "K14847", "K14793", 
"K06670", "K19009", "K13783", "K17963", "K15076", "K08492", "K15262", 
"K00901", "K00078", "K15133", "K21407", "K13566", "K14454", "K23565", 
"K09341", "K22414", "K00069", "K00069", "K07192", "K10276", "K11348", 
"K10389", "K06054", "K06590", "K06678", "K03671", "K17302", "K08155", 
"K23387", "K02951", "K12481", "K11434", "K18461", "K23439", "K13208", 
"K16803", "K20793", "K06269", "K16749", "K12737", "K14264", "K00857", 
"K21863", "K04459", "K01183", "K12856", "K23616", "K23195", "K09188", 
"K20193", "K21249", "K05765", "K04703", "K12259", "K24014", "K10141", 
"K11099", "K02263", "K01784", "K11884", "K24195", "K14810", "K15113", 
"K15283", "K14999", "K14776", "K11433", "K00228", "K03253", "K01410", 
"K05768", "K13288", "K07432", "K13718", "K11587", "K02912", "K15235", 
"K04351", "K23893", "K20730", "K10310", "K00558", "K15837", "K01205", 
"K11660", "K12021", "K23214", "K20791", "K07189", "K01507", "K16682", 
"K18163", "K13142", "K23901", "K17501"), mg = c("K19788", "K07874", 
"K00128", "K14793", "K06670", "K19009", "K13783", "K17963", "K19476", 
"K00078", "K13915", "K21407", "K14719", "K13524", "K22414", "K00069", 
"K00069", "K02178", "K12172", "K12866", "K13123", "K24254", "K17302", 
"K08155", "K02951", "K12481", "K11434", "K13208", "K17602", "K10571", 
"K13758", "K16749", "K00857", "K21863", "K06839", "K03241", "K04459", 
"K18200", "K01183", "K23616", "K10442", "K17563", "K05765", "K12259", 
"K10141", "K19326", "K10049", "K01784", "K00604", "K24195", "K15113", 
"K15283", "K19527", "K14999", "K01410", "K11587", "K02912", "K13109", 
"K15235", "K09595", "K23893", "K10310", "K11981", "K08858", "K00558", 
"K01205", "K11583", "K11660", "K05291", "K12021", "K18660", "K10393", 
"K23214", "K20791", "K06072", "K18163", "K17501", "K09848", "K23336", 
"K03064", "K02366", "K02377", "K14971", "K20290", "K13240", "K20185", 
"K01109", "K13125", "K16678", "K07964", "K05397", "K15175", "K08705", 
"K08561", "K02519", "K17824", "K13122", "K15338", "K12821", "K08752"
))

xx <- compareCluster(de_list, fun="enrichKEGG",
                     organism="ko", pvalueCutoff=0.05)
```

And the list of pathway IDs that I'd like to keep:

```
library(gage)
kg.ko = kegg.gsets("ko") # ("ko" is KEGG ortholog pathway)
kegg.gs = kg.ko$kg.sets[kg.ko$sigmet.idx] # keep only metabolic and signaling pathways
kegg.gs_names <-names(kegg.gs)
kegg.gs_names <- as.data.frame(gsub( " .*$", "", kegg.gs_names ))
names(kegg.gs_names) <- "ID"
```

So, I'd like to use `kegg.gs_names` to subset `xx`. The corresponding entry in `xx` is `xx@compareCluster$ID` while maintaining the structure of the clusterProfiler object for downstream plotting.

Here is the vignette (http://yulab-smu.top/biomedical-knowledge-mining-book/enrichplot.html). I'm trying to produce the plot in 15.7 without the disease pathways included.

Comment: I can't reproduce your code because "de_list" is missing but can't you transform xx@compareCluster to a dataframe and then subset ? Sorry but as I don't have de_list i don't figure out what does the object look like

Comment: @Basti - thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the text above. That was my initial thought as well, but the downstream plotting of these results require that the data remain in the same format as the initial object.